# update value of holder textview in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using google direction API to get the duration between my location and nearby places and it's working. But, I face problem in setting the duration value where the value is in `onPostExecute.I` tried to make duration global but it does not work. By the way, my textview is in `ViewHolder` class.

```html
public class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{
      
       String distance = "";
       String duration = "";
       // Parsing the data in non-ui thread     
      @Override
      public List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {
       
       JSONObject jObject; 
       List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;              
              
              try{
               jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
               DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
               
               // Starts parsing data
               routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
              }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return routes;
      }
      
      // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
      @Override
      public void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
       /*ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
       PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
       MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();*/
       
       
           
       if(result.size()<1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
       }
        
       
       // Traversing through all the routes
       for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
        
        
        // Fetching i-th route
        List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
        
        // Fetching all the points in i-th route
        for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
         HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j); 
         
         if(j==0){ // Get distance from the list
          distance = (String)point.get("distance");      
          continue;
         }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
          duration = (String)point.get("duration");
          continue;
         }
           
        }
        
        
       }
       
       
       //holder.val.setText("value"+duration);
       Toast.makeText(context,"Duration:"+duration ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       
       
       
      }
```

Comment: You can update on 'onPostExecute' method..

Comment: @RushabhPatel  BTW, Im use 2 layouts one for normal view and other for expandable one when I tried to set the value in layout 1 it's working but its seems my problem in layout 2 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
         int p=0;
         if (expandedView[p]) {
         holder.val.setText(duration);
         }
        }
       });